# Tkinter repeat process, with next button

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to build simple tkinter,
the GUI will display a text and user need to read the text and save the audio. my code currently works but the process not repeatable, my target when user press "NEXT" button the process will repeat the process... and when user press the "END" button process will stop.
is there anywhere how to done it?

```
 import sounddevice as sd 
  import soundfile as sf 
  from tkinter import *
  
def Voice_rec(): 
    fs = 48000
      
    # seconds 
    duration = 5
    myrecording = sd.rec(int(duration * fs),  
                         samplerate=fs, channels=2) 
    sd.wait() 
      
   
    return sf.write('save_audio.wav', myrecording, fs) 
  
master = Tk() 
import os, random
txtfile = random.choice(os.listdir(""))
txtread = "" + txtfile
with open(txtread, "r") as filek:
    textfile=filek.read()
#     Label(master, text=filek.read()).pack()  
wrapper = LabelFrame(master,text="sound record")
wrapper.pack(fill="both",expand="yes",padx=20,pady=20)


lbl3 = Label(wrapper,text=textfile,borderwidth=2, relief="solid",bg = "red")
lbl3.config(font=("Courier", 20))
lbl3.pack()  
    
#def next():
#    import os, random
#    txtfile = random.choice(os.listdir("path"))
#    txtread = "path" + txtfile
#    with open(txtread, "r") as filek:
#        textfile=filek.read()
    #     Label(master, text=filek.read()).pack()  
#    wrapper = LabelFrame(master,text="sound record")
#    wrapper.pack(fill="both",padx=20,pady=20)
#    lbl3 = Label(wrapper,text=textfile,borderwidth=2, relief="solid",bg = "red")
#    lbl3.config(font=("Courier", 20))
#    lbl3.pack()  
    
    
Label(wrapper, text=" Voice Recoder : "
     )#.grid(row=0, sticky=W, rowspan=5) 
  
b = Button(wrapper, text="Start", command=Voice_rec) 
b.pack()


c = Button(wrapper, text="Next", command=next) 
c.pack()
#b.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, 
 #      padx=5, pady=5) 
    
mainloop()
```

above code i refer from this link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/build-a-voice-recorder-gui-using-python/

Comment: Which is the function, you want to repeat.

Comment: the whole process, because the process related @CoolCloud

Comment: The answer below gives you the idea, follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you wrap this in a function:

```
txtfile = random.choice(os.listdir(""))
txtread = "" + txtfile
with open(txtread, "r") as filek:
    textfile = filek.read()
```

which you can then link to your `Next` button to load a new file each time.  Do not re-render the whole UI every time.

In other words, something like this:

```
master = Tk()
text_file = StringVar()
wrapper = LabelFrame(master, text="sound record")
wrapper.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=20)
lbl3 = Label(wrapper)


def next_audio():
    path = "path/"
    txtfile = random.choice(os.listdir(path))
    txtread = os.join(path, txtfile)
    with open(txtread, "r") as filek:
        text_file.set(filek.read())
    print(text_file.get())
    lbl3.configure(text=text_file.get())


next_audio()
lbl3.configure(text=text_file.get(), borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="red")
lbl3.config(font=("Courier", 20))
lbl3.pack()
```

Not the best looking code but that was not the intention, just to try and use your code to show what I mean.  Also perhaps a tip on Tkinter, rather use the `grid` geometry manager.  `pack` and `place` are not best practice with modern Tkinter.

Hope this helped?!

Comment: i try why your suggestion, but the text display after the recording have done. that means user does not know what to read since no text display but the recording already start.

Comment: This is because the text in `lbl3`  is not automatically updated.  You can achieve this by explicitly setting this at the time you hit `Next`:    `lbl3.configure(text=textfile)`

Comment: can you provide example? since is not working or my understanding are wrong based on your explanation. Tq